# Changing the line spacing of a TextBox in C#/WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-runtime

Is there any way to change the line spacing or line height of a TextBox in a C# WinRT app?

It's possible to do this with the TextBox element in WPF through a XAML attribute like so:

```
<TextBox TextBlock.LineHeight="10" TextBlock.LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight" />
```

Silverlight has a [LineHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.lineheight%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) attribute that can be directly applied to a TextBox element.

WinRT doesn't allow either of these.

In WinRT, it is possible to change the line height of the text in a RichEditBox like so (where `EditorBox` is a RichEditBox):

```
Windows.UI.Text.ITextParagraphFormat LineHeight = EditorBox.Document.GetDefaultParagraphFormat();
LineHeight.SetLineSpacing(Windows.UI.Text.LineSpacingRule.OneAndHalf, 1);
```

But this doesn't really help me as I want to change the line height of a TextBox element. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but you can do this programmatically by setting the property via [Block class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.block) ([WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.documents.block)).

```
TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
tbox.SetValue(Block.LineHeightProperty, 10.0);
```

In Xaml you don't even need to specify the stacking strategy or to refer to `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBox Block.LineHeight="10" />
```